# How do I return a new object from a mocked repository using a LINQ Expression?

Tags: c#, linq, rhino-mocks

I am using Rhino Mocks and have created a Mock Repository.

```
var salesForcePolicies = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository<SalesForcePolicy>>();
```

I have a private method to return a `policy` item from the repository.

```
private SalesForcePolicy GetSalesForcePolicyByClientId(decimal clientId)
{
    var policy = salesForcePolicies.FindByExp(x => x.IdNumber == clientId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (policy == null) throw new AccountUpdaterException("Policy Not Found in Sales Force Lookup Table.");
    return policy;
}
```

I am trying to get the repository to return a new object with one property set when the query is called in the `private` method. I do not want to break the encapsulation and set to `public virtual`.

The compiler is screaming when I write this...

```
var clientId = decimal.Parse("123456");
salesForcePolicies.Stub(x => x.FindByExp(y => y.IdNumber == clientId)).Return(new SalesForcePolicy { PolicyNumber = "123456" });
```

How can I get this mocked repository to return a new object when it is queried?

```
Error: The best overloaded method match for 'Rhino.Mocks.Interfaces.IMethodOptions<System.Linq.IQueryable<Data.Models.Ussi.SalesForcePolicy>>.Return(System.Linq.IQueryable<Data.Models.Ussi.SalesForcePolicy>)' has some invalid arguments.
```

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to this is pass in `null` for the expression argument and then use `.IgnoreArguments()`. For the return create a `new List<T>()` and call `.AsQueryable()`.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_Mock_Sales_Force_Repo()
{
    // arrange
    var salesForcePolicyRepo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository<SalesForcePolicy>>();

    // act
    var clientId = decimal.Parse("123456");
    var salesForcePolicy = new SalesForcePolicy { PolicyNumber = "123456" };
    IEnumerable<SalesForcePolicy> salesForcePolicies = new List<SalesForcePolicy> { salesForcePolicy };
    salesForcePolicyRepo.Stub(x => x.FindByExp(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(salesForcePolicies.AsQueryable());
    var policy = salesForcePolicyRepo.FindByExp(x => x.IdNumber == clientId).FirstOrDefault();

    // assert
    Assert.IsTrue(policy == salesForcePolicy);
}
```